# Compare values with BETWEEN from same columns as two different columns

Tags: sql

I'm storing myriad attributes from user-uploaded image files in a single table.  The basic structure of the table is like this:

```
attrib_id | image_id | attrib_name | attrib_value
```

Alongside attributes like `TAG` and `CAPTION`, I'm storing `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` of the image's location in the same manner.  All the columns are of type `varchar`.

I'm trying to query for images associated with locations within a given bounding box - the inputs are upper and lower latitude, start and end longitude.  The output of the query should be a list of `image_id`s that have a row with `name=LATITUDE` and `value BETWEEN upper and lower latitude`, as well as the same for longitude.

Since all the values are strings, and in the same columns, I don't really know where to start with this one.

While I'm willing to consider restructuring the table, my intuition tells me there's a way to accomplish this in SQL.

My database is currently MySql, but I'm likely to switch over to Postgres in the future, so I would prefer non-vendor specific solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table lat
INNER JOIN Table lon ON lat.image_id = lon.image_id
WHERE (lon.attrib_name = 'LONGITUDE' AND lon.attrib_value BETWEEN start AND end) AND 
(lat.attrib_name = 'LATITUDE' AND lat.attrib_value BETWEEN upper AND lower)
```

Not sure if `BETWEEN` is supported in Postgres or whatever you migrate to so you can just use `<` and `>` operators.

Comment: No, the `OR` is going to give me lots of locations that are outside the bounding box, and using an `AND` in its place will give me nothing

Comment: Updated. Now joining the table with itself since you need to compare two attributes from different rows.

Comment: Looks pretty good. Now I just need a cast from `varchar` to `double`, since the columns are all `varchar`

Comment: Cool. You need help with that or know how to do that?

Comment: I used `(lon.attrib_value + 0.0)` for the casting